# OpenLDAP ldapadd Invalid DN syntax (34)

Tags: ldap, openldap

I've been strugling/googling for hours about this, just trying a very simple thing add entries to my ldap using ldapadd (OpenLDAP on Ubuntu).

my structure.ldif looks like this :

```
dn: ou=Personnes,dc=odi,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: Personnes
description: Employes de l entreprise

dn: ou=Machines,dc=odi,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: Machines
description: Ordinateurs de l entreprise

dn: cn=Marie Dupond,ou=Personnes,dc=odi,dc=com
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
givenName: Marie
sn: Dupond
cn: Marie Dupond
uid: mdupond
userPassword: mdupond
```

and my ldap config :

```
version: 1

#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=odi,dc=com> with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ALL
#

# odi.com
dn: dc=odi,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: organization
o: odi
dc: odi

# admin, odi.com
dn: cn=admin,dc=odi,dc=com
objectClass: simpleSecurityObject
objectClass: organizationalRole
cn: admin
description: LDAP administrator
```

and I can understand why when I add it through ldapadd -x -W -D “cn=admin,dc=odi,dc=com” -H ldapi:/// -f structure.ldif Iget an ldap_bind: Invalid DN syntax (34)
additional info: invalid DN

Any help would be really appreciated,

Comment: the error message indicates the invalid DN is encountered when performing the `BIND` operation. Could there be something wrong with bind DN you are passing to `-D`?

Comment: well the DN should be what I passed as mentionned in ldap search

Comment: found the issue, dumb as always, was using  “ instead of ". i have no words...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same problem! Highlighted from your comment above:

```
was using “ instead of "
```

Not the same characters! How frustrating!